# QWidget::showMinimized() doesn't work

Tags: qt

On Ubuntu 13.04, if using `QWidget::showMinimized()` to minimize a window, I found that after restoring it by clicking the app icon the system taskbar, recalling the  `QWidget::showMinimized()` cannot work.

```
connect(minimumBtn,SIGNAL(clicked()),this,SLOT(minimumWin()));
minimumWin(){
   showMinimized();
}
```

`showMinimized()` in `minimumWin()` doesn't work anymore if it has been called before (even the window is showed).

Comment: I've read this question 3 or 4 times, and it still makes absolutely no sense. It might be helpful if you included some [sample code](http://sscce.org/) that reproduces the problem. And maybe a screenshot or two.

Comment: Use the [edit] link underneath your question. Comments don't support multiple lines or code formatting.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I can reproduce this with Linux Mint and Qt 5.1. It is most probably a bug in Qt. I found that if you call `showNormal()` right after `showMinimized()`, the window minimizes and after it is restored from the taskbar, it is possible to minimize the window again. For example:

```
void MainWindow::on_pushButton_clicked()
{
    showMinimized();
    showNormal();
}
```

Comment: If it's a reproducible bug, it's probably worth filing a bug report with the Qt team.

Comment: It seems that it is already reported: https://bugreports.qt-project.org/browse/QTBUG-25727

Answer (score 1):

I've met this problem, but I didn't solve it completely

In ubuntu system, you can use this function in your `QWidget` class constructor:

```
this->setWindowFlags(Qt::Window|Qt::FramelessWindowHint||Qt::WindowMinimizeButtonHint);
```

then the `showMinimized()` is valid to use (there is no frame and a minimize button when code running, if you have, then you're with me).

But it's only valid in ubuntu system, and this method is invalid in my company's customized (like ubuntu) operate system. I don't know why.